# Контрольный знак Code 128

Tags: python-3.x

Возможно ли реализовать расчёт контрольного знака по стандарту для штрих-кода Code 128 (для некой последовательности цифр) при помощи библиотек Python? Вывод самого изображения штрих-кода не нужен - только контрольный знак для заданного числа.

Comment: Всё давно реализовано.  pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi code128 --pre

Comment: О! Благодарю вас!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [0.8b1 версию `pyBarcode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyBarcode/0.8b1):

```
>>> import barcode  # $ pip install pybarcode --pre
>>> from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
>>> code = barcode.Code128('Stack Overflow', writer=ImageWriter())
>>> code.encoded
[104, 51, 84, 65, 67, 75, 0, 47, 86, 69, 82, 70, 76, 79, 87]
>>> code.build()
['110100100001101110100010011110100100101100001000010110011000010010110110011001000111011011110100100101100100001001001111010110000100110010100001000111101011110010100111011001001100011101011']
>>> code.to_ascii()
'XX X  X    XX XXX X   X  XXXX X  X  X XX    X    X XX  XX    X  X XX XX  XX  X   XXX XX XXXX X  X  X XX  X    X  X  XXXX X XX    X  XX  X X    X   XXXX X XXXX  X X  XXX XX  X  XX   XXX X XX'
>>> code._calculate_checksum(code.encoded)
27
```

Модуль простой, но неотшлифованный -- версия 0.8 (с code128) и документация к ней не опубликованы и вычисление контрольной суммы почему-то в виде частного метода только доступно.

```
>>> code.save('barcode-stackoverflow')
'barcode-stackoverflow.png'
```

[image: Code 128 Stack Overflow]

Если png картинка не нужна (по умолчанию svg генерится), то можно не передавать `writer` параметр при создании штрих-кода.

Comment: Благодарю. Ценная информация.